# IoC com Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, .net, ninject

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando IoC e Ninject para injeção de dependência, e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Ao fazer upload de minha aplicação para o servidor obtive o seguinte error:

[image: Tela de erro]

Alguem poderia me auxiliar em como resolver este erro?

Método IoC.Install

```
public static void Install()
        {
            DILoader.Install(
                (tInterface, tClass) => IoC.Register(tInterface, tClass),
                (tInterface, tClass) => IoC.RegisterInSingletonScope(tInterface, tClass),
                (tInterface, tClass) => IoC.RegisterInThreadScope(tInterface, tClass)
            );
        }
```

Aqui é onde carrego os Assemblies

```
 public static void LoadAssemblies()
    {

        var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();

        loadedAssemblies
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetReferencedAssemblies())
            .Distinct()
            .Where(y => loadedAssemblies.Any((a) => a.FullName == y.FullName) == false)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => loadedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(x)));
    }
```

Aqui é onde chamo esses metodos

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        LoadAssemblies();
        IoC.Install();
    }
```

Metodo onde registro os binds

```
public class NinjectIoCContainer : IIocContainer
    {

        private IKernel kernel;
        private IKernel Kernel
        {
            get
            {
                if (kernel == null) {
                    kernel = new StandardKernel();
                }
                return kernel;
            }
        }

        public void Register(Type tInterface, Type tClass)
        {
            Kernel.Bind(tInterface).To(tClass);
        }
        public void RegisterInSingletonScope(Type tInterface, Type tClass)
        {
            Kernel.Bind(tInterface).To(tClass).InSingletonScope();
        }
        public void RegisterInThreadScope(Type tInterface, Type tClass)
        {
            Kernel.Bind(tInterface).To(tClass).InThreadScope();
        }

        public TInterface Resolve<TInterface>()
        {
            return Kernel.Get<TInterface>();
        }

    }
}
```

Para fazer o bind ele pega as classes que tem o atributo como o exemplo abaixo

```
 [InstanceIoC]
    public class UCManterUsuario : IManterManterUsuario
    {
```

Comment: O Ninject não conseguiu encontrar nenhum tipo associado à interface `IManterUsuario` e sendo a mesma uma interface, ele não pode criar uma instância para injetar sem que uma associação seja fornecida. Você poderia postar seu código onde configura as associações do Ninject?

Comment: Coloque o seu codigo (onde cria o kernel e onde regista as dependencias) para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Adicionei mais detalhes!

Comment: Ainda não aparece o trecho de código onde você configura os bindings do Ninject. Você deve ter algum método parecido com esse: `public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) { kernel.Bind<IManterUsuario>().To<ImplemetaManterUsuario>(); }`

Comment: Nunca usei esse automatic loading. Aparentemente essa implementação não está conseguindo detectar o attributo `InstanceIoC`. Eu faria um teste pra descobrir se funciona configurando isso no método `Install()`:  `IoC.Register(typeof(IManterUsuario), typeof(UCManterUsuario ));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando a anotação `[assembly]` você pode configurar o método que será executado quando iniciado e terminado o *container IoC*.

Com isso não é necessário configurar o **Global.asax** para inicializar o *container* de injeção de dependências.

**App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs**

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly:WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace Aplicacao
{
    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                LoadAssemblies();
                IoC.Install();
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
         }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O Problema é que estava equivocado na forma como o IoC e o Ninject funciona,

O IoC onde carrega os assemblies precisa ser executado somente uma vez no ciclo de vida da aplicação, já o Ninject ele precisa ser executado toda vez que a aplicação é aberta.

Concluindo a solução está abaixo:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        LoadAssemblies();

    }

 protected void Session_Start()
    {

       IoC.Install();

    }
```

Comment: Ainda n está resolvido, a aplicação esta intermitente...heeeelp-mee